# Spark Scala Sequence Split on Integer Criteria

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using Scala on Spark and need some help splitting a sequence of sets based on specific values within the sets.

Here is an example:

```
val sets = Array(Seq(Set("A", 15,20 ),Set("B", 17, 21), Set("C", 22,34)),
  Seq(Set("D", 15, 20),Set("E", 17, 21), Set("F", 21, 23), Set("G", 25,34)))
```

I am trying to split each sequence within the array based off the criteria that the first integer within each set is between the two integers within the other sets in the same sequence and return the character value of the sets grouped together.

So for the first sequence you can see that we have the integers 15 and 20 in the first set and in the second set 17 and 21. So those sets would be grouped together because 17 is between 15 and 20 and the third set would not be left alone.

In the second sequence I have 15 and 20 overlaps with 17 and 21. Also 17 and 21 will overlap with 21 and 23 and then the last set would be left alone.

Essentially I would like to have it return `Set(A, B)`, `Set(C)`, `Set(D, E)`, `Set(D, F)`, `Set(G)`

I realize this is not great phrasing but if someone could give me a hand that would be very appreciated.

Comment: If you're trying it would be nice if you show us your efforts. SO is not a code writing service and questions like this usually get downvoted / closed. Also `Set` looks like a really bad choice here. Unless ensured otherwise by a specific implementation sets are not ordered. Not to mention all values have to be of the same type (here `Any`). Tuple looks like a reasonable replacement.

Comment: I am fiarly certain it will be in a shell like this:rddSets.flatMap(s =>
//s is a Seq(), e.g. Seq(1,2,3,4)
//then you go through each one and see if they overlap
//and you end up with say: Seq(1,2), Seq(3,4)
//or say Seq(1,2,3), Seq(4)
).map( x =>
//x now is Seq(1,2,3), for example

for i in seq:
//yield (1, i) as your edge
)

Comment: You can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33576805/edit) your question using a link located under the tags.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by the zero323, `Set("A", 15,20 )` should probably not be a set. I suggest converting it to a case class:

```
case class Item(name: String, start: Int, end: Int) {
  val range = Range.inclusive(start, end)    
}
```

With this class, if you described your problem correctly it could be solved like this:

```
sets.map { seq =>                           
  seq.foldLeft(Vector[Vector[Item]]()) { (list, item) =>
    list.lastOption match {                         
      case Some(lastGroup) if lastGroup.last.range.contains(item.start) => 
        list.init :+ (lastGroup :+ item) 
      case _ =>      
        list :+ Vector(item) 
    }                     
  }.map(l => l.map(i => i.name).toSet)
}.flatten
```

Comment: If you want to use `List` it is better to prepend (`::`) and work with the head of the list (and reverse at the end), instead of appending and working with the last element, since those operations are `O(n)` (vs `O(1)`). You could instead use `Vector`. (See [performance collections](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html)).

Comment: You are right. I knew that but didn't  think this would be a big issue for his case. Will update the answer.